# nginx ingress always redirecting to https even with configmap and annotations set

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have an ingress that is configured like such:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: connect-app
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: it.tufts.edu
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        backend:
          serviceName: connect-it
          servicePort: 80
```

and the nginx controller has a configmap that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  data:
    ssl-redirect: "false"
  kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"v1","data":null,"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"nginx-config","namespace":"nginx-ingress"}}
    creationTimestamp: 2018-11-13T20:56:49Z
    name: nginx-config
    namespace: nginx-ingress
    resourceVersion: "3633400"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/nginx-ingress/configmaps/nginx-config
    uid: a3ec70bc-e786-11e8-be24-005056a401f6
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

According to the documentation, this should disable the redirect from http to https but it doesn't seem to workout, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the nginx.conf from inside of your `pod`?

Comment: Hi, @Crou Sorry you mean the pod that is part of the service or the nginx-ingress pod?  The pod that is part of the service I'm trying to not have TLS on is an apache webserver: 

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/directory"
    ServerName it.tufts.edu

    DirectoryIndex index.html .index.html index.shtml index.pl index.cgi index.htm .index.htm

    <Directory "//directoryl">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Indexes Options=Indexes FileInfo
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost> `
~

Comment: Try adding annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` to the nginx-ingress yaml

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work.  when I have 443 in the nginx-ingress yaml it works fine, as soon as I take it out it breaks.  There has to be another place that its getting set that either isn't documented well or I"m just overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is either:

- A problem with your nginx ingress controller not updating the configs which you can check with:

  ```
  $ kubectl cp <nginx-ingress-controller-pod>:nginx.conf .
  $ cat nginx.conf
  ```
- A problem with your apache config redirecting to HTTPS from HTTP (port 80)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, people in from out of town.  In the ingress controller I see it creating a default-site and it has just port 80 in it and no ssl or port 443 in it like other ingresses we have setup.  Also, Apache isn’t redirecting as I csn tske thr Apache config from the image and have it work properly in a vm.  I’m getting the default nginx site so it has to be somewhere I. The controller.  Will post the output of the configs in a bit